# Advantage of passing by reference opposed to using global?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

im looking at the MVC pattern, and I can see in [one example on phppatterns](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/archive/model_view_controller_pattern#the_view) they're passing the model by reference -  any benefit of doing this over a global var? Am I missing something obvious?

```
class MyView extends View {
  var $model; 

  function __construct(&$model){
    $this->model =& $model;
  }

  function productTable($rownum=1) {
    $rowsperpage='20';
    $this->model->listProducts($rownum,$rowsperpage);
    while ( $product=$this->model->getProduct() ) {
         // Bind data to HTML
    }
  }
}
```

Any reason why you would do this as apposed to using a global variable? i.e.

```
class MyView extends View {
  global $model;

  function __construct(){ }

  function productTable($rownum=1) {
    $rowsperpage='20';
    $model->listProducts($rownum,$rowsperpage);
    while ( $product=$this->model->getProduct() ) {
         // Bind data to HTML
   }
}
```

Comment: Global variables kill puppies. That's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with global variables is that:

1. They assume that there is only one implementation of model and view.
2. They assume that there is only one instance of the model and view (you could have several of each in your application).
3. They hide the interdependency between components; your view is very strongly affected by the model, but not having to explicitly pass a model into your view  makes this implicit.

For other reasons why globals and singletons are "evil" (i.e. just really a poor design decision that you should never make), read [avoid global variables, environment variables, and singletons](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/avoid-global-variables-environment-variables-and-singletons).

Comment: Thanks Michael! Key point there, that it assumes only 1 instance -  and it will make seeing the links a little harder. I can see myself overlooking global variables and not handling them properly if im not explicitly passing them to the constructor .

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- the advantage is that you could change the implementation of the model without having to modify the View.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you need to modify the view in one case, but not in the other case? How does referencing the model instance depend on the implementation of the Model class?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use another tutorial, the one you're using is a bit outdated, and **isn't** PHP 5. That said, you really shouldn't use global variables, that's never the solution!

But I don't really get why you should even wanna pass it by reference, in PHP 5 it's already *passed by reference*:

```
class foo {
    public $a;
    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$a = new foo(10);
$b = $a;

$a->a = 20;

echo $a->a.' => '.$b->a; // 20 => 20
```

Comment: +1. Passing class instance by reference is an outdated technique.

Comment: Thanks GuidoH, thats how its done in more traditional programming languages i.e. Java anyway isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple (similar) model instances, on which you possibly would like to apply the same view, you would need to explicitly pass the model instance. A global variable assumes there could be only one model instance, and thus creates an artificial limitation.

Comment: Thanks, that was very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In general not using global variables is better to help you control the scope of your variables.

Comment: Agreed - I think i got tied up in trying to simplify the code and looking at PHP4 based frameworks!

Answer (score 0):

I won't mention about why that is a bad thing, because it has been already discussed. One thing that I think you should know is that the code provided there is PHP 4 compatible. In PHP 5 by default objects are sent by reference.